# jQuery "$ is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I swear I have included jquery in the page header, it is right there!

Nonetheless the following code, which I've included near the bottom of the page (and inline for now) gives me an error saying "TypeError: $ is not a function."

```
<script>
        function displayResult(longA, latA, longB, latB, units) {
            $("#distance").html(calcDist(longA, latA, longB, latB, units));
            if (units=="m") {
                $("#unitLabel").html("miles");
                $("units").prop("selectedIndex",0);
            } else {
                $("#unitLabel").html("kilometers");
                $("#units").prop("selectedIndex",1);
            }
            $("#longA").val(longA);
            $("#latA").val(latA);
            $("#longB").val(longB);
            $("#latB").val(latB);
        }

        $("#calculateButton").click(function() { //This is the line it's complaining about
            var longA=$("#longA").val();
            var latA=$("#latA").val();
            var longB=$("#longB").val();
            var latB=$("#latB").val();
            var units=$("#units").val();
            displayResult(longA, latA, longB, latB, units);
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Higher up in the page header I've got the following:

```
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script src="calcDistSinglePage.js" ></script>
```

I'm not using Wordpress or anything, this is a very straightforward hand-coded HTML page.

Comment: Are you *sure* that "jquery.js" is the right path to your jQuery file? I would try opening up developers tools and checking out the navigation tab to see if jquery file is actually getting hit.

Comment: Also the `(jQuery)` part is weird. `.click` doesn't return a function, it returns a jQuery object. You cannot call a jQuery object.

Comment: Make sure the path is correct. If it's in a different folder than the page you're linking it to, this path would be incorrect.

Comment: })(jQuery); .. where are you getting this one to be onclick?

Comment: Try inspect element, and open the jquery link in new tab, see if it point to the correct path.

Comment: KJ and Tim, the path is correct, I'm not getting 404s. 

Felix, you're absolutely right. That bit of code still needs a tidy-up, I'm trying to call a function on click.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping your code in a closure (which is considered good practice anyways):

```
(function($) {
    $("#calculateButton").click(function() {
      // do stuff...
    });
}(jQuery));
```

If this snippet still complains with the same error, there's bound to be a problem with the way you're loading the jQuery library.

Also, make sure that you don't overwrite the `$` variable in your other code. For example, inside `calcDistSinglePage.js`.

The dollar-sign is a very straight-forward javascript variable and can be reassigned to whatever you want. According to the error, `$` currently is *something* but *not* a function (otherwise you'd receive a ReferenceError stating that `$` is undefined). So probably, somewhere in your code, you've overwritten it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the **jQuery library** it's the first script you load.

Add this just before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-{{JQUERY_VERSION}}.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

- Download the file locally and inside js/vendor/ add the file.
- Replace the value {{JQUERY_VERSION}} in the script above adding your jquery version.

Here one CDN you could use.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You are probably linking it from a root folder that is not your HTML folder. Use an absolute path:

```
<script src="/jquery.js" ></script>
```

Or make sure `jquery.js` is in the *same* folder as your HTML.